# How can I find out if a read error on a optical disk is due to corrupted file system or physical damage?

Tags: data-recovery, optical-media

I have a video DVD that I'm trying to extract but that is very hard to read (takes several days and not finished).

**Is there any way to find out if the problem is a physical damage of the surface of the optical disc, or some corruption in the file system?**

I'm asking because the disc has no visible physical damages, and I want to take proper action in the continued tries to extract it data. E g need to know if a polishing of the surface of the disc might help.

Comment: Does dmesg contain any related messages? You could try dumping it as an ISO file with `dd if=/dev/dvd of=disk.iso`, this reads the disk's raw data, so if the problems persists, it should be with the disk or the drive.

Comment: Have you tried copying it with `dvdisaster` first?

Comment: @crater2150 `if=/dev/dvd of=disk.iso` is indeed very slow, and gets stuck, so I guess that means that the drive has a hard time to read time DVD.